# How to write a shell script to execute a java file using maven

Tags: java, shell, maven

I want to create a shell script which when called run the following command
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="location_of_class_file" -Dexec.args="parameter";

Comment: did you write anything? Do you know basics of shell scripting?

Comment: do you have a Google installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you use Maven, you can specify your main class in the pom file. This value will be parsed and will be stored in the manifest file of the jar. So the argument `-Dexec.mainClass="location_of_class_file"` can be omitted.

If maven (mvn) is in your PATH variable, you can directly paste your command inside `<filename>.sh` and execute it.
You can create the `<filename>.sh` with `touch`. Remember to give it execute permissions with `chmod`. E.g. if your filename is let's say "hui" (that's a common filename used for testing) it will look like:

```
touch hui.sh
chmod u+x hui.sh
```